# In bash, looking for a number in a txt and use it as a variable in a bash script

Tags: python, bash, perl, text, find

I have a bash script which may use a variable that is inside the process.txt

The precess.txt has this form:

```
Processing triangulated mesh.       
 => Generating   
 => Preparing    
 => Infilling   
 => Generating  
 => Exporting   
Done. Process took 0 minutes and 4.739 seconds.  
Filament required: 4849.4mm (34.3cm3).
```

and I would like to get the filament value as a variable (in this case is 4849.4)

I have no idea how it could be done. maybe in python or perl?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using `grep`:

```
$ NUM=$(grep -Po '(?<=Filament required: )[0-9\.]*' process.txt)
$ echo $NUM
4849.4
```

Answer (score 0):

Using python  `re`:

```
   s = """
Processing triangulated mesh.
 => Generating
 => Preparing
 => Infilling
 => Generating
 => Exporting
Done. Process took 0 minutes and 4.739 seconds.
Filament required: 4849.4mm (34.3cm3)."""


import re 

print(re.findall("Filament required:\s+(\d+\.\d+)",s))
4849.4
```

Just open the file and read:

```
with open(your_file) as f:
   print(re.findall("Filament required:\s+(\d+\.\d+)",f.read()))
4849.4
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way using `awk`

```
NUM=`awk -F':' '$1~/^Filament/{split($2,a," "); gsub('/[^0-9.]/',"",a[1]); print a[1]}' process.txt`
echo "$NUM"
4849.4
```

### Explanation

- `-F':'` specifies the field separator
- `$1 ~ /^Filament/ {...}` does something -- indicated in `{...}` -- to lines where field1 (`$1`) matches (`~`) a regular expression with a string starting (`^`) with `Filament`
- `split($2,a," ")` splits field2 (`$2`) by `" "` into an array labelled `a`
- `gsub('/[^0-9.]/',"",a[1])` replaces any characters in element1 of the array (`a[1]`) that are not a digit or a period (`[^0-9.]`) with nothing `""`
- `print a[1]` prints the the result

Answer (score -2):

Using pipes:

$ num=$(cat process.txt|grep Filament|cut -d " "  -f 3|cut -d "m" -f 1)

$ echo $num